# Swift: Call a function in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a `TableViewController` to handle my data and a `sortFunction`. What I want to do is to call the `sortFunction` in a `SortViewController` and when the Button "done" is clicked go back to my `TableViewController` (which should show the sorted data now)

My Question is: how can I call the `sortFunction()` which is included in my `TableViewController` in the `SortViewController`?

This what I have:

#### TableViewController:

```
func sortFunction(){
    self.data?.sortInPlace({ $0.clicks > $1.clicks })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

#### SortViewController:

When the specific sort Button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func sortBestClicks(sender: AnyObject) {
    // how to call the function from TableViewController here??
}
```

When Done is Clicked:

```
@IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToStart", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: it seems like it would make more sense to put `sortFunction()` into `SortViewController`. do you have a reason not do so? otherwise this would be the most straightforward and sensible solution.

Comment: you want just call sortFountion() right ?

Comment: yeah I tried this but I need to call  self.tableView.reloadData() too to update the TableView and there is no TableView in mit SortViewController

Comment: ah ok, then another option might be to pass the sorted data back to the table view in unwind segue once it got sorted in the `SortViewController` who has the `sortFunction()` (which then is only responsible for sorting but not for displaying the data, if I got you right)

Comment: This sounds good. How can I pass the data back to the tableview?

Answer (score 3):

In TableViewController viewDidLoad add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotification", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

and add a method in TableViewController like

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification() {

    sortFunction()

}
```

in SortViewController call the method with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Hope this helps you.

You could also use a delegate protocol.